# Running javascript on Khan academy page

Tags: javascript, khan-academy

[image]

I'm working through The Algorithms section of Khan Academy. I'm  working on the challenge at https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/p/challenge-binary-search

How do I run the program, after I write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs automatically. Try removing the `println` line of code and you will see the black box that is outputting the result disappears.

Comment: it's `println`, not `print_in`, btw. :)